# How does DISTINCT ON work in GCP datastore

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore

Let's say I have a kind named 'audit' and it has the following entries:

| tenantId | traceId | eventId |
| --- | --- | --- |
| tenant1 | traceId1 | event1 |
| tenant1 | traceId1 | event2 |
| tenant1 | traceId2 | event3 |
| tenant1 | traceId2 | event4 |

I need to get all the rows unique on traceId whichever is the first entry
so the query should result in:

| tenantId | traceId | eventId |
| --- | --- | --- |
| tenant1 | traceId1 | event1 |
| tenant1 | traceId2 | event3 |

For the above, I am using `select distinct on(traceId) * from audit`

Even though it's a simple query, my concern is the performance of this query as my entries grow. I will have hundreds of thousands of entries in the datastore, but out them, 50% might be unique on traceId.

I have read datastore is not for aggregations. So, my questions are:

1. Is distinct on considered an aggregation query?
2. Does distinct on work on index scan?
3. Will distinct on increase my read cost?
4. Will the built-in index handle the distinct on or should we define a composite index?

Answer (score 1):

> Is distinct on considered an aggregation query?

`distinct on` clause ensures that only the first result for each distinct combination of values for the specified properties will be returned. So it is not considered as an aggregation query. Also Datastore does not support aggregation queries.

> The index-based query mechanism supports a wide range of queries and is suitable for most applications. However, it does not support some kinds of query common in other database technologies: in particular, joins and aggregate queries aren't supported within the Datastore mode query engine.

You can read about it in [this document](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/queries)

> Does `distinct on` work on index scan?

Yes, `distinct on` works on index scan and you can not apply `distinct on` to any of the unindexed properties.

> Will `distinct on` increase my read cost?

If you are using [projection queries](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/queries#projection_queries) then using `distinct on` will increase the cost as it will make the query out of small operations as mentioned [here](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/pricing#small_operations). If you are not using projection queries then it will charge based on the entity reads.

> Will the built-in index handle the distinct on or should we define a composite index?

If you are applying `distinct on` to a single property i.e. `select distinct on(traceId) * from audit`, then it will work with the built in index that is created during the entity creation. If you are applying `distinct on` to multiple properties i.e. `select distinct on(traceId,eventId) * from audit` then it will not work with the built in index and you have to create a composite index.

Comment: Thank you for explaining the points, and bringing in more clarity. How distinct on work with index scan. If you could provide any links which explain that.

Comment: You mention "If you are using projection queries then using distinct on will increase the cost as it will make the query out of small operations as mentioned here. If you are not using projection queries then it will charge based on the entity reads." Does `*` in `select distinct on(traceId) * from audit` considered as projection query?

Comment: I don’t have any reference link but when I try to run a query with `distinct on` in a property which is not indexed then it says [`Make sure there are either simple or composite indexes for the properties you are searching.`](https://i.imgur.com/Kz4fC8P.png), which indicates that it works on index scan.

Comment: Most queries return whole entities as their results, but often an application is actually interested in only a few of the entity's properties. [Projection queries](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/queries#projection_queries) allow you to query for just those specific properties of an entity that you actually need, at lower latency and cost than retrieving the entire entity. So in your case with `select distinct on(traceId) * from audit` you are using `*` to get all the properties of an entity hence it will not be considered as a projection query